# Whats is the meaning of formula in Matlab Guide for Fractal Dimension?

Tags: matlab, fractals

What does this formula mean?

```
df = -diff(log(n))./diff(log(r));
disp(['Fractal dimension, Df = ' num2str(mean(df(4:8))) ' +/- ' num2str(std(df(4:8)))]);
```

It should represent fractal dimension somehow, since I found it on [this web page from Mathworks](https://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/community/36051-computing-a-fractal-dimension-with-matlab-1d-2d-and-3d-box-counting). I don't understand how, though.

Answer (score 1):

The formula involves an attempt to estimate the [box-counting dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) of the image of this tree:

[image]

The box-counting dimension can be estimated by

```
dim(E) ≈ -log(N)/log(r)
```

where N is the number of squares that cover an image and r is the side length of the squares in the cover. In fact, the dimension is defined to be the limit of this expression as r goes down to zero. Thus, we typically have a sequence of r values that go down to zero which yields a sequence of N values that grow up to ∞. We can then extrapolate the limit from those values.

Now, in the formula to which you refer:

```
-diff(log(n))./diff(log(r))
```

`n` and `r` are both finite sequences generated by a box-counting command. Thus, in the numerator, `diff(log(n))` forms the sequence of consecutive differences of the log applied to those `n` values and, in the denominator `diff(log(r))` does a similar thing for the `r` values. The dotted quotient then forms the pairwise quotient of these two differences. The mean of the results is evidently one way to extrapolate the limit. I wouldn't think it would be one of the best ways, though.

Comment: Why use Diff here? this is my challenge.

Comment: @Mina You want a certain slope - the fractal dimension can be interpreted as the slope of the line that best approximates the points (log(n),(log(r)). If this sequence is not a line, the underlying object does not really have a fractal dimension. Taking the average of the slopes has the benefit of being less sensitive to artifacts in the picture, and cancelling measurement errors.